# Add multiple columns inside a tableview cell

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

[image: Click here to see the picture]

I'm trying to create a table that have a column inside a cell. Is there an easy way to implement this design to the table view I'm working with?

This is my code right now:

```
class ColumnsLayout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ColumnsLayout, self).__init__(parent)
        table_row = QTableWidget()
        table_row.setColumnCount(3)
        table_row.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        for x in range(0, 3):
            table_row.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(x, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addWidget(table_row)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

```
self.ui.fields_tableWidget.setCellWidget(self.current_default_total_row, 2, ColumnsLayout())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setSpan()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSpan) to join cells

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class ColumnsLayout(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ColumnsLayout, self).__init__(parent)
        table_row = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 3)
        table_row.horizontalHeader().hide()
        table_row.setSpan(0, 0, 1, 3)
        for x in range(0, 3):
            table_row.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(x, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addWidget(table_row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ColumnsLayout()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]